# Apollo cache + automatic refresh

Tags: caching, graphql, apollo

I have got an Angular 7 app that accesses data from a GraphQL server.

I directly implemented the example from the docs:
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching.html#automatic-updates

This is the service that get the post object and executes the upvote mutation.

```
export class PostService {

  constructor(private apollo: Apollo) { }

  public getPost() {
    return this.apollo.query({
      query: gql`query getPost($id: String!) {
        post(id: $id) {
          id
          score
        }
      }`,
      variables: { id: '123' }
    });
  }

  public upvote() {
    return this.apollo.mutate({
      mutation: gql`mutation upvote($id: String!) {
        upvotePost(id: $id) {
          id
          score
        }
      }`,
      variables: { id: '123' }
    });
  }
}
```

in my component.ts file

```
  public post = this.postService.getPost();
  public vote() {
    this.postService.upvote().subscribe(console.log);
  }
```

in my component.html

```
    <input type="text" [value]="(post | async).data.post.score" />
    <button class="button" (click)="vote()"></button>
```

The value in the box does not change.

If I add an additional button that calls this function

```
public updateView() {
  post = this.postService.getPost();
}
```

The gui will update without querying the server, so obviously from cache.

According to the spec this manual refresh step is not supposed to be necessary.

```
If the id field on both results matches up, then the score field everywhere in our UI will be updated automatically!
```

Versions of my packages:

- apollo-angular: 1.5.0
- apollo-angular-link-http: 1.4.0
- apollo-angular-link-http-common: 1.4.0
- apollo-cache: 1.1.25
- apollo-cache-inmemory: 1.4.2
- apollo-client: 2.4.12

What do I need to change so the result will actually be updated in the observable that was returned by the original request?

Or do I just not understand the intended mechanisms?

Comment: You're writing an Angular application but you've posted documentation for the React Apollo client?

Comment: Now that you mention it... :(

Answer (score 2):

A bit of a wild guess here, but I'm going to suggest this is due to the fact that you're not writing inline Queries; the documentation is going to differ somewhat. Take a look at the `refetchQueries` prop that you can pass to your Mutation, i.e.

```
  public upvote() {
    return this.apollo.mutate({
      mutation: gql`mutation upvote($id: String!) {
        upvotePost(id: $id) {
          id
          score
        }
      }`,
      variables: { id: '123' },
      refetchQueries: [],
    });
```

When your mutation executes, you're telling GraphQL that you want to execute the queries that you provide in that `refetchQueries` array. As a result of this, the cache will update. However, I'm not 100% convinced that your query will execute because you're not technically subscribed to it, all you've done is execute a one-time promise to fetch the data from the GraphQL endpoint.

Comment: The one-time-promise is not a Promise but an Observable. It is probably still "one time". As i described before, the cache already did update after the mutation, but this change is not reflected in the GUI.

Answer (score 2):

Now that I used the angular part of the docu instead of the React part, I found the solution. (@tombraider Thank you for pushing me in the right direction.)

Instead of `query`, I need to use `watchQuery`.

```
  public getPost(id: string) {
    return this.apollo.watchQuery({
      query: gql`query getPost($id: String!) {
        post(id: $id) {
          id
          score
        }
      }`,
      variables: { id }
    }).valueChanges;
  }
```

This changed version of the service-function keeps updateing the GUI.